# Service Worker error with hosted site

Tags: ubuntu, nginx, ssl

I am having problems with a hosted site. It works locally. But ever since I added my ssl cert. I've been running into issue after issue. This most current one I can't seem to pinpoint where it's coming from. I have tried completely removing the service worker from my app and it still has the same issue. The specific errors on the console are:
1: GET https://www.snagmysac.com/static/js/main.e3833e90.js 404 (Not Found)
2:The script resource is behind a redirect, which is disallowed.
3: Failed to load resource: net::ERR_UNSAFE_REDIRECT

There are not a lot of resources that I've found online that reference these errors.

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name snagmysac.com www.snagmysac.com;
    return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
}

server {
listen 443 ssl;
server_name snagmysac.com;

ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/snagmysac.com/fullchain.pem;
ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/snagmysac.com/privkey.pem;

ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
ssl_ciphers 'EECDH+AESGCM:EDH+AESGCM:AES256+EECDH:AES256+EDH';

root /usr/share/nginx/html;
index index.html index.htm;

location / {
  proxy_pass  http://127.0.0.1:8080;
  proxy_next_upstream error timeout invalid_header http_500 http_502 
  http_503 http_504;
  proxy_redirect off;
  proxy_buffering off;
  proxy_set_header  Host  $host;
  proxy_set_header  X-Real-IP   $remote_addr;
  proxy_set_header  X-Forwarded-For   $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
 }
}
```

Any ideas as to what is happening with the hosted server?

Comment: Do you really mean to have Express serve all your static content? Then why run nginx at all? Set `root` correctly and use `try_files`.

Comment: @MichaelHampton I didn't intend to have express serve my static files. But now I can't seem to figure out how to go back to just serving the backend

Comment: See [here](https://geekflare.com/nginx-static-files-node-js/) for a sample configuration.

Comment: Thanks! @MichaelHampton. I figured out. Turns out I needed to clear my cache, and then my redirect needed some fixing and now shes up and running again. Thanks for the link.

Answer (score 0):

I figured this out by trying a few different things. I cleared my cache and that seemed to solve part of the problem. But then I noticed my redirect wasn't working as it should so I fixed the redirect with a conditional return of the redirect.

```
server {
  listen 80;
  listen 443 ssl http2;
  server_name snagmysac.com www.snagmysac.com;
    if ($scheme = "http") { # Only redirect if not using SSL
     return 301 https://$server_name$request_uri;
}

ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/snagmysac.com/fullchain.pem;
ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/snagmysac.com/privkey.pem;

ssl_ciphers 'ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:AES256+EECDH:AES256+EDH';

location / {
# THESE ARE IMPORTANT
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
# This is what tells Connect that your session can be considered 
secure,
# even though the protocol node.js sees is only HTTP:
proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
    proxy_set_header X-NginX-Proxy true;
    proxy_read_timeout 5m;
    proxy_connect_timeout 5m;
    proxy_redirect off;
root /home/sitedir/;
proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8080;
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
}
```